# what is the meaning of "torsion group annihilated by integer"?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Provide examples for:

(1) a group that is neither torsion-free nor torsion

(2) a torsion group which is not annihilated by any integer

(3) a torsion-free but not free group

(4) a torsion-free but not free abelian group

Here is my thought and question:

(1) Is $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}$ a such example? since $(1,0)$ is not torsion-free, and $(0,1)$ is not torsion.

(2) What does it mean by "annihilated by any integer"?

(3) Is $\mathbb{Z}^{\infty}$ an example? I am not sure. any other good example?

(4) Is SL(n) an example?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is good: the group $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}$ is neither torsionfree because $(1,0)\ne(0,0)$ is annihilated by $p$, while $(0,1)$ has not finite order.

(2) You are required to find a torsion group $G$ such that, for every $n>0$, there exists $x\in G$ with $nx\ne0$. Hint: $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$

(3) You have to find a torsionfree group that is not free; is $\mathbb{Q}$ a free group?

Comment: Thank you! For (2), yes, you are right, $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is OK. FOr (3), I think $\mathbb{Q}$ is free since it can be generated by $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. I maybe wrong, since I just learn this concept.

Comment: @YiLi No, $\mathbb{Q}$ is not free: there are relations between those generators: $m\frac{1}{m}+(-n)\frac{1}{n}=0$.

Comment: OK, thank you very much!

Comment: @YiLi Indeed, the group $\mathbb{Q}$ has rank $1$ (only one element sets can be linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}$). You could try and prove that no divisible group is free abelian.